# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException al modificar una lista

Tags: java, lista

Basicamente tengo un problema que dice asi:

Cuando  se  trata  de  dar  autógrafos,  la  cola  de  personas  que  quieren  uno suyo puede ser de cuadras enteras. Pero sucede que las personas que hacen la cola de los autógrafos de Serena son muy impacientes.

Si  al  llegar  a  formarse,  la  cantidad  de  personas  en  la  cola  es  igual  o superior  a  un  máximo  que  cada  persona  define,  simplemente  no  se  forman  en  ella. Además, si en algún momento el tamaño de la cola supera ese máximo todos aquellos.

Con  ese  máximo prefieren  salirse,  lo  cual  es  gracioso  considerando que con solo  uno que lo haga ya el tamaño quedaría por debajo de ese valor(aparte de impacientes no tienen muy buena lógica que digamos).

Por ejemplo, si llega una persona cuyo máximo es 5 y en ese momento la cola tiene 8 personas no se formará siquiera.

En cambio, si llega una persona cuyo máximo es 10 y en ese momento la cola tiene 9 personas se formará, pero en el momento que supere ese valor tanto ella como todas las demás con ese mismo máximo se saldrán.

Este es mi este codigo

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<Integer> Tamaño = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    LinkedList<Long> Cedula = new LinkedList<Long>();
    Iterator<Integer> Iterador = Tamaño.listIterator();
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    String S;
    int i, T, L = 0;
    short R = 0;
    boolean vall = true;
    long C, N;
    while (vall) {
        S = entrada.next();
        if (S.equals("fin")) {
            break;
        }
        if (S.equals("ingresa")) {
            C = entrada.nextLong();
            Cedula.add(C);
            T = entrada.nextShort();
            Tamaño.add(T);
            if(Tamaño.get(Tamaño.lastIndexOf(T)) <= Tamaño.size()){
                Tamaño.removeLast();
            }
            R++;
            Iterador = Tamaño.listIterator();
            while(Iterador.hasNext()){
                i=Iterador.next();
                if((Tamaño.get(0))<= (Tamaño.size()) && R>1){
                    Tamaño.removeFirst();
                }
                else{
                    if(Tamaño.get(Tamaño.indexOf(i))<= Tamaño.size()&&  
                    R>1){
                        Tamaño.remove(Tamaño.indexOf(i));
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
            if (S.equals("cuenta")) {
                    N = Tamaño.size();
                    System.out.println("Personas en la cola: " + N);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

si analizan bien, todo funciona "bien" hasta que la entrada es:

> ingresa 1000002 4

> ingresa 1000003 4

> ingresa 1000004 4

> ingresa 1000005 4

> ingresa 1000006 5

y me sale el siguiente error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
> at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.checkForComodification(LinkedList.java:966)
> at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(LinkedList.java:888)
> at Main.main(Main.java:32)
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1

no se que hacer :c.

Comment: Usa un `synchronizedList()`. Así evitas la `ConcurrentModificationException`

Comment: @VictorHerasmePerez ¿Te importaría decir por que se tiene que usar una lista sincronizada? Por lo que veo no se estan usando varios hilos para modificar la lista.

Comment: La [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/148713/70224) que acaban de publicar lo explica. En otras situaciones he resuelto ese problema con una `Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkeList<>())`, aunque no sé si aquí funcione

Answer (score 3):

Tu problema está aquí:

```
        Iterador = Tamaño.listIterator();
        while(Iterador.hasNext()){
            i=Iterador.next();
            if((Tamaño.get(0))<= (Tamaño.size()) && R>1){
                Tamaño.removeFirst();
            }
            else{
                if(Tamaño.get(Tamaño.indexOf(i))<= Tamaño.size()&&  
                R>1){
                    Tamaño.remove(Tamaño.indexOf(i));
                }
            }   
        }
```

Básicamente lo que dice el error es que estás recorriendo una lista y modificándola a la vez. Es decir, estás recorriendo la lista Tamaño, y dentro del bucle while estás eliminando elementos de esa misma lista, cosa que no se puede hacer porque te da un ConcurrentModificationException. Lo mejor que puedes hacer es crearte una lista auxiliar, TamañoAux por ejemplo, y dentro del bucle que recorre Tamaño, añadir a TamañoAux los elementos que sí te valen. Una vez fuera del while, copias los valores de TamañoAux en Tamaño.